# Find objects who do not have an associated object created in last year

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a `Runner` class:

```
class Runner
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attended_happenings, through: :attendances, source: :happening
end
```

I want to create a query that gets all the runners who have attended a happening, but not in the last year. How would I do that?

I've tried something along the lines of `Runner.joins(:attended_happenings).where("happenings.created_at < ?", 1.year.ago).uniq` but obviously that will grab runners who have attended a happening more than a year ago but those runners could have also attended a happening within the last year, which I don't want. I guess I could subtract runners who do have an attended_happening within the last year like so:

```
runners = Runner.joins(:attended_happenings).where("happenings.created_at < ?", 1.year.ago).uniq - Runner.joins(:attended_happenings).where("happenings.created_at > ?", 1.year.ago).uniq
```

But that seems like it's super inefficient?

Comment: Hello David, please be sure you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid downvoting of your questions

Comment: Please, share with us what you already did so far to solve your challenge.

Comment: Hey Alex thanks for the feedback. I've updated with my attempts - please let me know if I should be doing anything else. The link you shared suggested an accurate title but didn't really know how to phrase it properly!

Comment: Can I see your schema?

Comment: I would look into using something like `.having("(SELECT count(*) FROM happenings WHERE happenings.created_at > ?)  = 0", 1.year.ago).group('happenings.id')`. It would help if you actually can create a full example with schema, models, and example of the data and the desired output to remove any guess work and to help people want to spend time on your problem actually test the code for real.